# ajax and htaccess issue

Tags: ajax, .htaccess

i using htaccess for change url:

```
localhost/test/broker.php?id=1
```

change to

```
localhost/test/1
```

htaccess code:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)   broker.php?id=$1    [QSA,L]
```

in my code also manually add page name to the url for exp

```
localhost/test/1/iphone
```

and still page load and working.

now my problem is using ajax in broker.php and if url to be without "iphone" word work correctly but with "iphone" word not working and without response

this is my ajax code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'yt.php',
    data: "broker_id=" + $("#broker_id").val() + "&uname=" + $("#uname").val() + "&email=" + $("#email").val() + "&country=" + $("#country").val() + "&rating=" + rating + "&review=" + $("#review").val(),
```

also i had a lot of changes in htaccess for broker.php and also for yt.php but my problem not solved!

please help me and tell what is wrong?

Comment: Can you show the exact URL that is not working, and what response code you are getting? You will be able to see both in the "net" tab of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: i used developer tools and show me yt.php , status 404 , this url not working : http://localhost/test/1/iphone but this working http://localhost/test/1

Comment: i found my problem and now working !